# Xrdp on Ubuntu: "Failed to execute default web browser input output error"

Tags: 22.04, xfce, remote-desktop, xrdp

I am running Ubuntu and have set up an xrdp server for remote desktop access. When I connect to the server using xrdp, everything works fine except for the default web browser.
I encounter the error message: "Failed to execute default web browser: Input/output error."

Ubuntu version: 22.04.3 LTS
Xrdp version: 0.19.17
Desktop environment: xfce4

When I connect to the server locally, my default web browser opens without any issues. However, when I connect remotely via xrdp, I receive the error: "Failed to execute default web browser: Input/output error."
Other applications work fine during the xrdp session

Steps Taken:

- I have verified that the web browser (e.g., Firefox) is installed on
  my Ubuntu server.
- I set the default web browser explicitly for my
  xrdp session in the ~/.xsession file.
- I checked for filesystem errors
  using sudo fsck, but no errors were found.
- I restarted the xrdp
  service after making changes to the configuration.
- I looked into
  system logs (e.g., /var/log/xrdp.log, /var/log/xrdp-sesman.log,
  /var/log/syslog) but didn't find any specific error messages related
  to this issue.

Comment: Please [update your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1491167/edit) with the specifics of how do you try to open the browser. Do you click on the Firefox icon? Do you enter a command (what?) in a terminal? Also copy and paste the content of the `.xsessionrc` file directly in your question. Then format it as `code` using the {_} icon above the Edit Question window.